# Posted notes on Newsfeed displayed incorrectly

Tags: 2013, my-site, newsfeed

I am finding it hard to find any information relating to how notes are posted onto newsfeeds with SharePoint 2013.

In particular our mysite newsfeed is displaying notes used within libraries, blogs and wiki articles. I am referring to Tags & Notes.

**My question is:** Are these notes being displayed correctly and if not, how can I rectify this?

Example of library doc and wiki article post(using page layouts):

[image]

Example of blog note post(assume is correct):

[image]

As you can see the wiki and document post looks different, is that how it is meant to be or am I meant to be getting something similar to the blog post, with actual title of post etc?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you indeed found a bug in SharePoint 2013.  Since Microsoft is not currently taking bug submissions on http://connect.microsoft.com for SharePoint, the only way to get them to look at this is with a support case.

Comment: The social features of SharePoint have always been lacking compared to other products.  If you are looking for a more fully-fledged social platform that works with SharePoint, you could check out NewsGator Social Sites (http://www.newsgator.com). (Disclaimer: I work for NewsGator, but I know how painful it can be to make SharePoint's built-in social features work on an enterprise level).